# setting values in an excel pivotTable Filter using VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, vba

I have a pivot table, whos source is a powerpivot model in the excel 2010 document.
I have two columns in the filter section of the pivot table. I need to set their values via VBA.

I have had a lot of trouble doing this. Id appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how to set conditions of filters by VBA?

Comment: yes, exactly. Currently trying a number of different ways, but the below lines are a general idea of what im trying to do, if i could just get it to work:

<code>
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tests")
               pt.ClearAllFilters
               pt.PivotFields("[CaseReceivedDate].[Year].    [Year]").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=2014
</code>

Comment: Ive narrowed it down to this which i think is closer but still not working.
     
     
     Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tests")
               pt.ClearAllFilters
               pfy.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals,     Value1:="[CaseReceivedDate].[Year].&[2014]"